# Make python for loop go only once

Tags: python, facebook

Alright, so I'm trying to make a Facebook bot over here to do some stuff for me, But I don't really think that matters for you.

Anyway, in order to achieve what I want to do I need to do some stuff. So, using the Facebook API I am getting some posts id with the following code:

```
for posts in parsed_json:
    post_id = posts.get('id')
    post_url = "http://facebook.com/" + str(post_id)
    text_save(post_url)
```

But the problem is that this code gets me the last 25 post ID's and I only need the last one. 
So bassicaly what I'm trying to do is: Get the last post ID and then execute the text_save() function with that.

But that loop gets me 25 ids, and I don't need them. I need only the first one.

So how do I limit the for loop to run only once? I tried the following thing:

```
a = 0
while a < 1:
    for posts in parsed_json:
        post_id = posts.get('id')
        post_url = "http://facebook.com/" + str(post_id)
        text_save(post_url)
        a = a + 1
```

But that didn't really work out, it still goes through it 25 times. Any ideeas?

Comment: If you only need one, why use a loop at all? Just use `post_id = parsed_json[0].get('id')`.

Comment: @chepner I was trying to work out that myself - the only possible explanation I could conjure up was if it's a streaming iterator/generator rather than an indexable sequence, and the attempt they've tried appears to be the first rather than the last anyway... baffled

Comment: Well then set the `limit` parameter to 1, so that the API will return (at most) one record in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last value (or first), simply use `"http://facebook.com/" + str(parsed_json[-1].get('id'))` (or parsed_json[0])

If you want to use loop instead,
to save just the last value, iterate and run the command afterwards:

```
post_url = ''
for posts in parsed_json:
    post_id = posts.get('id')
    post_url = "http://facebook.com/" + str(post_id)
text_save(post_url)
```

To break from a loop after one interation use:

```
a = 0
for posts in parsed_json:
    if a >= 1: break
    post_id = posts.get('id')
    post_url = "http://facebook.com/" + str(post_id)
    text_save(post_url)
    a += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one iteration, then basically you don't need a loop here.

But considering that you need to test some functionality, a `break` statement can terminate the loop.

```
a = 0
while a < 1:
    for posts in parsed_json:
        post_id = posts.get('id')
        post_url = "http://facebook.com/" + str(post_id)
        text_save(post_url)
        a = a + 1
        break
    break
```